# remove some retrieved records from query results by join table attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a query similar to this:

```
SomeModel.includes(:some_join_table).where(name: name, some_join_table: {*** STUFF ***})
```

in the some_join_table there is a field for the related id from SomeModel and a disallowed boolean column. How can I get that query to return every record where name == name and not include records where id == id and disallowed == true?

Answer (score 0):

> not include records where id == id and disallowed == true

You can transform this condition to: Either `x.id <> y.id` or `disallowed = false`.

Not sure about the Ruby syntax, but this query would do what you ask (as long as `disallowed` is defined `NOT NULL` - I am assuming `id` is the PK (which cannot be null):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM   SomeModel m
JOIN   some_join_table j USING (name)
WHERE  m.id <> j.id OR NOT j.disallowed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add more where clauses

```
SomeModel.includes(:join_table).where(:name => name).
  where.not(:join_table => {:id => 10})
```

For example

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(:subject => "Hello").
  where.not(:comments => {:id => 10})
```